# Systemd fails to compile on arm environment

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, cross-compiling, systemd

Im trying to compile systemd in a qemu chroot environment.
The environment is built with cross compiler and using gcc 11.2.
I have tried with systemd 249, 247 and 246.
They all gives the same error.

meson is succeeded and the options is:

```
meson --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --buildtype=release -Dblkid=true -Ddefault-dnssec=no -Dfirstboot=false -Dinstall-tests=false -Dldconfig=false -Dman=false -Dsysusers=false -Drpmmacrosdir=no -Db_lto=false -Dhomed=false -Duserdb=false -Dmode=release -Dpamconfdir=/etc/pam.d -Defi=false -Dgnu-efi=false -Dtpm=false
```

When running ninja it complains about assert.
Here are some of the failed:

```
[13/1524] Compiling C object src/udev/ata_id.p/ata_id_ata_id.c.o
FAILED: src/udev/ata_id.p/ata_id_ata_id.c.o
cc -Isrc/udev/ata_id.p -Isrc/udev -I../src/udev -Isrc/basic -I../src/basic -Isrc/fundamental -I../src/fundamental -Isrc/systemd -I../src/systemd -I. -I.. -I../src/libsystemd/sd-bus -I../src/libsystemd/sd-device -I../src/libsystemd/sd-event -I../src/libsystemd/sd-hwdb -I../src/libsystemd/sd-id128 -I../src/libsystemd/sd-journal -I../src/libsystemd/sd-netlink -I../src/libsystemd/sd-network -I../src/libsystemd/sd-resolve -Isrc/shared -I../src/shared -fdiagnostics-color=always -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Wextra -std=gnu99 -O3 -Wno-format-signedness -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-result -Wdate-time -Wendif-labels -Werror=format=2 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=overflow -Werror=return-type -Werror=shift-count-overflow -Werror=shift-overflow=2 -Werror=undef -Wfloat-equal -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Winit-self -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wmissing-noreturn -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wpointer-arith -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -Wstrict-prototypes -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wwrite-strings -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Werror=missing-declarations -Werror=missing-prototypes -fdiagnostics-show-option -ffast-math -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector -fstack-protector-strong -fvisibility=hidden --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Werror=shadow -include config.h -MD -MQ src/udev/ata_id.p/ata_id_ata_id.c.o -MF src/udev/ata_id.p/ata_id_ata_id.c.o.d -o src/udev/ata_id.p/ata_id_ata_id.c.o -c ../src/udev/ata_id/ata_id.c
In file included from ../src/basic/macro.h:4,
                 from ../src/basic/fd-util.h:9,
                 from ../src/udev/ata_id/ata_id.c:27:
../src/fundamental/macro-fundamental.h:38:9: error: static assertion failed: "STRLEN(__FILE__) > STRLEN(RELATIVE_SOURCE_PATH) + 1"
   38 |         static_assert(expr, #expr)
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/basic/log.h:65:1: note: in expansion of macro 'assert_cc'
   65 | assert_cc(STRLEN(__FILE__) > STRLEN(RELATIVE_SOURCE_PATH) + 1)
      | ^~~~~~~~~

[14/1524] Compiling C object src/core/libcore.a.p/dbus-device.c.o
FAILED: src/core/libcore.a.p/dbus-device.c.o
cc -Isrc/core/libcore.a.p -Isrc/core -I../src/core -Isrc/basic -I../src/basic -Isrc/fundamental -I../src/fundamental -Isrc/systemd -I../src/systemd -I. -I.. -I../src/libsystemd/sd-bus -I../src/libsystemd/sd-device -I../src/libsystemd/sd-event -I../src/libsystemd/sd-hwdb -I../src/libsystemd/sd-id128 -I../src/libsystemd/sd-journal -I../src/libsystemd/sd-netlink -I../src/libsystemd/sd-network -I../src/libsystemd/sd-resolve -Isrc/shared -I../src/shared -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -fdiagnostics-color=always -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Wextra -std=gnu99 -O3 -Wno-format-signedness -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-result -Wdate-time -Wendif-labels -Werror=format=2 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=overflow -Werror=return-type -Werror=shift-count-overflow -Werror=shift-overflow=2 -Werror=undef -Wfloat-equal -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Winit-self -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wmissing-noreturn -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wpointer-arith -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -Wstrict-prototypes -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wwrite-strings -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Werror=missing-declarations -Werror=missing-prototypes -fdiagnostics-show-option -ffast-math -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector -fstack-protector-strong -fvisibility=hidden --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Werror=shadow -include config.h -fPIC -pthread -MD -MQ src/core/libcore.a.p/dbus-device.c.o -MF src/core/libcore.a.p/dbus-device.c.o.d -o src/core/libcore.a.p/dbus-device.c.o -c ../src/core/dbus-device.c
In file included from ../src/basic/macro.h:4,
                 from ../src/basic/alloc-util.h:9,
                 from ../src/basic/hash-funcs.h:4,
                 from ../src/basic/hashmap.h:8,
                 from ../src/shared/fdset.h:6,
                 from ../src/shared/bpf-program.h:9,
                 from ../src/core/unit.h:10,
                 from ../src/core/device.h:4,
                 from ../src/core/dbus-device.c:4:
../src/fundamental/macro-fundamental.h:38:9: error: static assertion failed: "STRLEN(__FILE__) > STRLEN(RELATIVE_SOURCE_PATH) + 1"
   38 |         static_assert(expr, #expr)
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/basic/log.h:65:1: note: in expansion of macro 'assert_cc'
   65 | assert_cc(STRLEN(__FILE__) > STRLEN(RELATIVE_SOURCE_PATH) + 1);
      | ^~~~~~~~~\

[9/1511] Compiling C object src/libsystemd/libsystemd_static.a.p/sd-bus_bus-creds.c.o
FAILED: src/libsystemd/libsystemd_static.a.p/sd-bus_bus-creds.c.o  
cc -Isrc/libsystemd/libsystemd_static.a.p -Isrc/libsystemd -I../src/libsystemd -Isrc/basic -I../src/basic -Isrc/fundamental -I../src/fundamental -Isrc/systemd -I../src/systemd -I. -I.. -I../src/libsystemd/sd-bus -I../src/libsystemd/sd-device -I../src/libsystemd/sd-event
-I../src/libsystemd/sd-hwdb -I../src/libsystemd/sd-id128 -I../src/libsystemd/sd-journal -I../src/libsystemd/sd-netlink -I../src/libsystemd/sd-network -I../src/libsystemd/sd-resolve -fdiagnostics-color=always -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Wextra -std=gnu99
-O3 -Wno-format-signedness -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-result -Wdate-time -Wendif-labels -Werror=format=2 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=overflow -Werror=return-type -Werror=shift-c
ount-overflow -Werror=shift-overflow=2 -Werror=undef -Wfloat-equal -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Winit-self -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wmissing-noreturn -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wpointer-arith -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -Wstrict
-prototypes -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wwrite-strings -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Werror=missing-declarations -Werror=missing-prototypes -fdiagnostics-show-option -ffast-math -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector -fstack-protector-strong -fvisibility=hidde
n --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Werror=shadow -include config.h -fPIC -pthread -fvisibility=default -MD -MQ src/libsystemd/libsystemd_static.a.p/sd-bus_bus-creds.c.o -MF src/libsystemd/libsystemd_static.a.p/sd-bus_bus-creds.c.o.d -o src/
libsystemd/libsystemd_static.a.p/sd-bus_bus-creds.c.o -c ../src/libsystemd/sd-bus/bus-creds.c
In file included from ../src/basic/macro.h:11,
                from ../src/basic/alloc-util.h:9,
                from ../src/libsystemd/sd-bus/bus-creds.c:6:
../src/fundamental/macro-fundamental.h:42:22: error: size of array 'x' is negative
  42 |                 char x[(expr) ? 0 : -1];                                \
     |                      ^
../src/basic/log.h:65:1: note: in expansion of macro 'assert_cc'
  65 | assert_cc(STRLEN(__FILE__) > STRLEN(RELATIVE_SOURCE_PATH) + 1);
     | ^~~~~~~~~
```

Im not very experienced in cross compiling and got some info from https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable-systemd/ and [https://github.com/LeeKyuHyuk/PiCLFS/\](https://github.com/LeeKyuHyuk/PiCLFS/%5C)

/Mikael

Comment: I wonder what you get for `RELATIVE_SOURCE_PATH`.  Can you search for it in your `config.h`?

Comment: It looks like this: #define RELATIVE_SOURCE_PATH "/tmp/mtpkg/source/systemd-246". 
Its the root of the source folder, does not look relative to me.

Comment: I manually changed the #define to "../" and it seems to be building now. I think i missed a line in the systemd section of lfs which is "..". I will try it in my build script and post the results.

Comment: Huh, I'm still getting this even though my `RELATIVE_SOURCE_PATH` already is `..`

Comment: Is it an slash in the end: ../ ?

Answer (score 1):

#define RELATIVE_SOURCE_PATH is being set to absolute path.
Changing it to #define RELATIVE_SOURCE_PATH "../" solves the issue